# Copy first row to the last in file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

The purpose here is to copy the first row in the file to the last

Here the input file

```
335418.75,2392631.25,36091,38466,1
335418.75,2392643.75,36092,38466,1
335418.75,2392656.25,36093,38466,1
335418.75,2392668.75,36094,38466,1
335418.75,2392681.25,36095,38466,1
335418.75,2392693.75,36096,38466,1
335418.75,2392706.25,36097,38466,1
335418.75,2392718.75,36098,38466,1
335418.75,2392731.25,36099,38466,1
```

Using the following code i got the output desired. Is there other easy option?

```
  awk 'NR==1 {print}' FF1-1.csv > tmp1
  cat FF1-1.csv tmp1
```

Output desired

```
335418.75,2392631.25,36091,38466,1
335418.75,2392643.75,36092,38466,1
335418.75,2392656.25,36093,38466,1
335418.75,2392668.75,36094,38466,1
335418.75,2392681.25,36095,38466,1
335418.75,2392693.75,36096,38466,1
335418.75,2392706.25,36097,38466,1
335418.75,2392718.75,36098,38466,1
335418.75,2392731.25,36099,38466,1
335418.75,2392631.25,36091,38466,1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following solution may also help on same:

***Solution 1st:*** Simply using `awk` with using `RS` and `FS` here(without using variables):

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '{print $0 ORS $1}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Using `cat` and `head`:

```
cat Input_file && head -n1 Input_file
```

Answer (score 6):

Save the line in a variable and print at end using the [END](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html#Using-BEGIN_002fEND) block

```
$ seq 5 | awk 'NR==1{fl=$0} 1; END{print fl}'
1
2
3
4
5
1
```

Answer (score 5):

`head`can produce the same output as your `awk`, so you can `cat` that instead.

You can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to avoid the temporary file.

```
cat FF1-1.csv <(head -n 1 FF1-1.csv)
```

---

As mentionned by [Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/) if process substitution isn't available you can simply `cat` the file then `head` it sequentially to obtain the same result, putting both in a subshell if you need to redirect the output :

```
(cat FF1-1.csv; head -n1 FF1-1.csv) > dest
```

---

Another alternative would be to pipe the output of `head` to `cat` and refer to it with `-` which for `cat` represents standard input :

```
head -1 FF1-1.csv | cat FF1-1.csv -
```

Comment: good one, in case process substitution is not available, `cat file; head -n1 file` to display the result, `(cat file; head -n1 file) > op_file` to save the result and so on..

Answer (score 4):

When you want to overwrite the existing, normal solutions can fail: do not write to a file you are working with.
A solution for editing the `file` is:

```
printf "%s\n" 1y $ x w q | ed -s file > /dev/null
```

Explanation:
`printf` will help for entering all commands in new lines.
`1y` will put the first line in a buf.
`$` moves to the last line.
`x` will paste the contents of the buf.
`w` will write the results.
`q` will quit the editor.
`ed` is the editor that performs all work.
`-s` is suppressing diagnostics.
`file` is your input file.
`> /dev/null` is suppressing output to your screen.

Comment: Could also use `1t$` to copy the first line to the end (checked with `GNU ed`, not sure about other implementations).

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed:

```
seq 1 5 | sed '1h;$G'
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
```

---

> `1h`: In first row: copy current row (pattern space) to sed's hold space
>
> `$G`: In last row (`$`): append content from hold space to pattern space

---

See: `man sed`

Answer (score 0):

A fun alternative is to use `head` and `tail`. You can use `tail -n+2 file` to output beginning with line 2 and then use `head -n1 file` to output the first record:

**Using Bash and Process Substitution with cat**

```
$ cat <(tail -n+2 file) <(head -n1 file)
335418.75,2392643.75,36092,38466,1
335418.75,2392656.25,36093,38466,1
335418.75,2392668.75,36094,38466,1
335418.75,2392681.25,36095,38466,1
335418.75,2392693.75,36096,38466,1
335418.75,2392706.25,36097,38466,1
335418.75,2392718.75,36098,38466,1
335418.75,2392731.25,36099,38466,1
335418.75,2392631.25,36091,38466,1
```

or

**Posix Shell Using printf with Command Substitution**

```
$ printf "%s\n" $(tail -n+2 file) $(head -n1 file)
335418.75,2392643.75,36092,38466,1
335418.75,2392656.25,36093,38466,1
335418.75,2392668.75,36094,38466,1
335418.75,2392681.25,36095,38466,1
335418.75,2392693.75,36096,38466,1
335418.75,2392706.25,36097,38466,1
335418.75,2392718.75,36098,38466,1
335418.75,2392731.25,36099,38466,1
335418.75,2392631.25,36091,38466,1
```

(note: if the records contain whitespace, the `printf` trick will not work and temporary files will be needed)

**note:** this requires multiple processes and reading the file twice. `sed`/`awk` with a single pass are always the preferred choice. This is just an additional alternative describing how `head` and `tail` can be used to accomplish the same goal.